# Import Toon Shaded Character to an outside program?

Tags: modeling, shaders

I made a character and added toon shading but I can't see it. After some research it seems that toon shading is only visible if you render the image with a camera in the blender scene. I want to import the cel shaded model to Unity so I have to need for a camera or light source since I will have to use Unity's. Is it possible to export a "cel shaded" character?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since a shader is calculated real-time, and not something that can be feasibly stored and exported, this is not possible. Unless unity has a feature to interpret blender's settings and simulate blender's toon shading, which I don't think it does.

---

I've never used unity, but this pretty much applies to importing and exporting to/from any program.

Comment: I didn't know that but it makes sense. I assumed that it would change the "skin" of the mesh in Blender and make it permanent. When you import to Unity it always imports without color, you then have to also import the skin (texture might be the right word, not sure, but it's what I uv unwrapped and color) and drag it to the model. This will then rewrap the skin around your model and it will do it correctly too.

Comment: Textures can be imported/exported because they are a static predetermined image (sometimes it's animated, but it's just a sequence of static images) with a defined mapping which can also be stored. The shading is generated and calculated on the fly, based on light sources etc.

Answer (score 2):

I cannot say for certain if it can or can't be done, but I would advise against it regardless. Unity comes with a few toon shaders that are fine for most cases and are guaranteed to work with the engine.

What you do instead is that you export the mesh object by itself and build the material you want for it inside Unity. You also assign the texture for it in Unity if your object has one.

If you feel you need more control over the toon shader, there are some solutions over at the Unity Marketplace you could try.

Comment: Yea I have seen the unity toon shader but I assumed it would be better to handle all the art stuff in Blender. I guess I'll give Unity's a try but blender just has more options

Answer (score 2):

For a toon shader to keep it's appearance based on camera angle you will want to use a unity shader.

If you want to use blender's toon shader to define a static appearance then you can bake a texture in blender to an image and use an image texture in unity. While baking is most commonly known for creating normal or bump maps you can also bake out entire textures as well.

Bake options are available under the render properties panel and up until 2.70 are only available for the blender render engine. Cycles baking is currently in progress to be included in 2.71