# Rendering mesh edges as solid lines

Tags: rendering, freestyle, draw-mode

I have a black and white image which serves as a template for my game.
Non selected country borders are white, and selected country borders should be outlined by solid black lines.
[image]
Each country border is represented by a mesh which I position over a country.

Meshes are created in Blender using BezierCurves and convert to mesh option.

Is it possible to create a material in a simple manner, which would make my 2d mesh render as solid black lines, to achieve select/deselect effect?

I'm quite new at Blender and didn't manage to achieve it via FreeStyle component for mesh outlining.

**QUESTION UPDATE**

Managed to render solid lines in Blender render view.

[image]

When you export your mesh from Blender, is your material exported also?

Because when I imported the mesh into Unity, the mesh was not rendered.

Meshes without faces aren't visible in Unity, so I expected my material to
make the mesh visible.

Every advice will be appreciated :)

**CONCLUSION**

The outline effect can be achieved in Blender relatively easily, but you cannot export
it in my case.

The mesh must be shaded with a Unity compatible shader and materials used must be built 
inside Unity in most cases.

Sadly, free version of Unity doesn't allow writing shaders in OpenGL, Unity shader syntax must be used.

Thx, everyone!

Comment: No. see http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/9215/599

Comment: @gandalf3, thx for the pointer! Seems I'll have to use a Unity compatible shader to achieve the desired effect.