# Fade out object with alpha value

Tags: animation, export

I was wondering how to fade out an object and export it as an animation? I saw another question that said to add a keyframe at full alpha and another at 0, and that works for the most part. I'm trying to export it using the ogrexml plugin so I can use the animation in my game. I'm using blender 2.65

Comment: I suspect it'd be easier to do any material animation in the game engine. Related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/9215/599

Comment: Oh gotcha. So material done in the engine, and bones done in blender.

Comment: Any particular reason for using an older version of Blender? Just curious since you mentioned it.

Comment: Not sure. I haven't had any issue with it so I don't feel the need to upgrade it

Comment: @user16713 I get what you mean. I used to think that way too. But I've found over the years that many features I had hoped would be added or improved on actually did end up getting updated in subsequent versions. It's totally worth it to stay current. :-)