# Exporting render image into Photoshop and still get material distortions

Tags: rendering, export

Apologies if this question has already been asked.  I'm completely new to Blender and I want to use it to create 3D objects for compositing in Photoshop.

I don't know if this is even possible but here goes.  I've created a basic model that has arms and legs.  I've set it to be transparent so it looks like glass in Blender.  With another object behind my model you can see the distortion this glass material creates.

I open the blender file (.3ds) in Photoshop which treats it as a 3D object.  Doesn't look pretty to begin with.  What I notice straight off is that a photo  I drop in behind my 3D object layer isn't distorted at all.

Does anyone know if this it's possible to have 3D objects distort a 'normal' photo layer in Photoshop?

Comment: I think you'd be better off rendering out the normals pass and trying to use that to distort the image in photoshop, or even better, importing the .psd into blender as a 2D plane behind the object. Photoshop has no way of knowing that the object is supposed to distort the image for a [whole slew](http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/9184/599) of [practical reasons](http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/9215/599)..

Answer (score 2):

No need to take the 3D to photoshop. Bring the image to blender instead.

Go to user preferences (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>ALt</kbd> <kbd>U</kbd>)
Enable the **import images as planes** addon.

[image]

On the 3D viewport you can add images as plane (<kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>A</kbd>).
Then select the *psd (PNG, Tiff, JPEG, etc) image you want to import.
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks all for replying so quickly, that did the trick!  :o)

Answer (score 0):

I stitch together an HDRI environment map backplate first with no movement and add it in as an environment map. I then add the footage as a shadeless material on an image-as-plane in cycles and place it behind the element, parented to the camera. (Make sure to remove any lense distortion from your footage so that distortion added to the camera doesn't compound the footage distortion. That's a huge tell.) I then add additional reflection plates behind the camera filmed in front of a green screen to simulate ambient backround activity. An alternate method, if you can afford it, is to buy a 360 camera and film cars, actors, etc to the rear of the camera, along with a few frames of empty environment. Use those last few frames to mask out unwanted background elements, maybe even photoshopping them a little. Then create the shadeless plane as before. Either way, you need an environment map or you'll wind up with grey artifacting. If I make a tutorial, I'll post it.