# Cycles Integrating glass into live footage

Tags: cycles-render-engine, workflow, compositing-nodes, transparency, render-passes

I'm trying to integrate transparent objects rendered with cycles into live footage. The problem is that when compositing, even with alpha, the original grey sky is rendered through the glass instead of the footage. I'm wondering what the proper workflow is for cycles-live integration, and what principle I'm misunderstanding in this failed attempt.[image: Screenshot] Here's an example of trying to use the image (soon to be movie) as an environment map: [image]

Comment: If your glass is transparent use the Alpha Over node, not Z Combine. If you want refraction or reflection in glass you need to have the image as environment in cycles.

Comment: That works for stills, if I create an HDRI environment map. However, it doesn't work for a movie clip.

Comment: I added an example image.

Comment: related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/30331/exporting-render-image-into-photoshop-and-still-get-material-distortions