# Glass object on video

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, video, glass

i'm new on Blender 3D and i want to realized something.

I have a video during 250 frames, i just want to add a text object using Glass BSDF Surface material it is possible ?

Thanks for answer.

Comment: You can animate visibility of the object.  See: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/88980/38953

Comment: I don't want to delete my object or want the object to disappear, i want it to be glass bsdf during the video

Comment: Maybe the language is not coming through well enough.  Please explain more clearly.  You want the text to have a Glass shader and that's it?  Or you want to animate (change) the shader from one to another?

Comment: I have a video during 250 frames, so something move. I want to put a text in front of the video and do glass on it. Like this i want to see the video behind the text while being able to read it. Sorry if i'm not well with my english ^^

Comment: Or maybe can i put my video on the text too ? maybe that should be an other solution...

Comment: You need to use the video as texture on a plane, then add the glass object in front: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/30331/exporting-render-image-into-photoshop-and-still-get-material-distortions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the add images as planes addon to create a plane that has the video as texture for an emission shader.

Then add the text and give it a glass shader and place it in front of the plane.

For additional integration you might want to use the video as background for the world, that way the video will also be used for the reflectinons on the glass.

[image]